# POSTGRES. error: extra data after last expected column. one double quote?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, psql

I have a massive database, and I found an error, when the migration is a single ", returns the error.

```
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
```

my data is

```
   ...
    0,direccion N"16, 109, 420000
    0,otra direccion N"32", 109, 320000
   ...
```

my command to migrate

```
$ psql -U user sat -c "copy table FROM '/file.csv' WITH  (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER(','));"
```

The strange thing is that when I erase the double quotes and can migrate, there will be some way to escape or ignore `"`

Comment: What is the `'['` supposed to mean?  The delimiter appears to be a `','` (and the quote is none)

Comment: sorry , I corrected it `,`

Comment: FYI, `,` is the default delimiter when using `FORMAT csv`.

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes are the default quotation character for the `COPY` command. Use the `QUOTE` option to modify this:

```
psql -U user sat -c "copy table FROM '/file.csv' WITH  (QUOTE '~', FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER(','));"
```

See [PostgreSQL COPY Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html)